# calling methods of classes more efficiently

Tags: python, class, oop, methods, tk-toolkit

i'm not having any trouble with my code i just wanted to see if there was a shorter way of doing

```
def taskcreator(first,second,third):
    first.needs()
    second.needs()
    third.needs()
```

like if i can do something like

```
def taskcreator(first,second,third):
    (first,second,third).needs()
```

since i will creating a'lot more objects, and i like to minimise my code count and make my code more efficient.
thanks for your help in advance.
Here's the whole code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

screen = tk.Tk()

class Crop:
    def __init__(self,sizename,sizevar,onvar,xvalue,yvalue):
        sizevar = tk.StringVar()
        self.sizename = sizename
        self.sizevar = sizevar
        self.onvar = onvar
        self.offvalue = 'no'
        self.cb = tk.Checkbutton(screen, text=self.sizename, variable=self.sizevar, onvalue=self.onvar, offvalue=self.offvalue)
        self.cb.deselect()
        self.cb.place(x=xvalue, y=yvalue)

    def needs(self): 
        value = self.sizevar.get()
        print(value)
        if value != 'no':
            print(self.sizename + ' has been checked')
        else:
            print(self.sizename + ' has not be checked')


def main():

    labell = tk.Label(screen, text='Enter Shoe Link').place(x=10, y=20)
    first = Crop('UK 2.5', 'twohalf', 'twohalfon', 10, 110)
    second = Crop('UK 3', 'three', 'threeon', 200, 110)
    third = Crop('UK 3.5', 'threehalf', 'threehalfon', 10, 150)
    fourth = Crop('UK 4', 'four', 'fouron', 200, 150)
    fith = Crop('UK 4.5', 'fourhalf', 'fourhalfon', 10, 190)
    sixth = Crop('UK 5', 'five', 'fiveon', 200, 190)
    seventh = Crop('UK 5.5', 'fivehalf', 'fivehalfon', 10, 230)
    eigth = Crop('UK 6', 'sixth', 'sixthon', 200, 230)
    ninth = Crop('UK 6.5', 'sixthhalf', 'sixthhalfon', 10, 270)
    tenth = Crop('UK 7', 'seven', 'sevenon', 200, 270)
    newtaskbutton = tk.Button(screen, text='Start', command=lambda: taskcreator(first,second,third))
    newtaskbutton.place(x=30,y=10)

def taskcreator(first,second,third):
    first.needs()
    second.needs()
    third.needs()
main()
screen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getattr` and `*args` to achieve this:

```
def taskcreator(*args):
    for arg in args:
        getattr(arg, 'needs')()
```

`*args` takes all of the arguments passed into a function, and stores them all as a `tuple` called `args`.

`getattr` gets the an attribute of an object by name - in this case the `needs` attribute of each `arg`

Comment: Great - if it's solved your problem, please consider accepting this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: You don't need to use `getattr`; `arg.needs()` will work.

Comment: Yes - I added `getattr` as I wasn't certain that only the method would be dynamic - but if it's only ever going to be `needs` then `getattr` is redundant.